# existential instantiation and generalization in coq

Tags: coq

Can someone please give me a simple example of existential instantiation and existential generalization in Coq? When I want to prove `exists x, P`, where `P` is some `Prop` that uses `x`, I often want to name `x` (as `x0` or some such), and manipulate P. Can this be one in Coq?

Comment: i know there have been coq questions here in the past, but i suspect that as more sites are introduced the best place for coq questions is now http://cs.stackexchange.com/ (not so happy with the fragmentation myself, but it's a fact of life...)

Comment: @andrewcooke [This hasn't been established conclusively.](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52/scope-limits-on-proof-assistants-e-g-coq) My feeling is that Coq questions are more on-topic on SO if the goal is to get a proof done, and on [cs.se] if the goal is to understand why a proof technique is working or not working, but it's a very thin line. The expertise is spread over [so], [cs.se] and [cstheory.se].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're going to prove the existential directly and not through a lemma, you can use `eapply ex_intro`. This introduces an existential variable (written `?42`). You can then manipulate the term. To complete the proof, you need to eventually provide a way to construct a value for that variable. You can do this explicitly with the [`instantiate`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#instantiate) tactic, or implicitly through tactics such as `eauto`.

Beware that it is often cumbersome to work with existential variables. Many tactics assume that all terms are instantiated and may hide existentials in subgoals; you'll only find out when `Qed` tells you “Error: Attempt to save an incomplete proof”. You should only use existential variables when you have a plan to instantiate them soon.

Here's a silly example that illustrates the use of `eapply`.

```
Goal exists x, 1 + x = 3.
Proof.                        (* ⊢ exists x, 1 + x = 3 *)
  eapply ex_intro.            (* ⊢ 1 + ?42 = 3 *)
  simpl.                      (* ⊢ S ?42 = 3 *)
  apply f_equal.              (* ⊢ ?42 = 2 *)
  reflexivity.                (* proof completed *)
Qed.
```

Comment: With Coq trunk you can turn uninstantiated existentials into subgoals at the end of the proof - which is something I wished for for a long time.

Comment: An addition to [the previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686164/existential-instantiation-and-generalization-in-coq#comment13933112_10693631): this can be done with [`Grab Existential Variables.`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual009.html#GrabEvars)